# Python, Kivy: Multiple Checkboxes Interfere With User Interface

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am creating myself a password generator and I have run across this issue. I have put two checkboxes and one text input. Wherever I click on the screen, it deactivates/activates the bottom-most checkbox. You could run my code (it's the full code, nothing excluded) and see what happens.

**.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
import string

sm = ScreenManager()

class main(Screen):
    def generate(self):
        include_num = self.ids.include_num.active
        include_special = self.ids.include_special.active

        letters = list(string.ascii_letters)
        special = list(string.punctuation)
        numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

        if self.ids.len_of_password.text:
            pass

        else:
            self.ids.len_of_password.text = 'NEEDED'

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm.add_widget(main(name='main'))

        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

^^ I still haven't put the logic in because of the issue, please do not focus on giving me the logic. Rather, I am looking for a solution for the multiple checkboxes issue.

**.kv**

```
<main>
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'Length:'
            font_size: 70
            pos_hint: {'right': 0.85,'y': 0.3}

        TextInput:
            multiline: False
            id: len_of_password
            text: '20'
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.15
            font_size: self.height / 4 * 3
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.55, 'y': 0.725}

        Label:
            text: 'Include numbers?'
            font_size: 45
            pos_hint: {'right': 0.85, 'y': 0.1}

        CheckBox:
            active: True
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.2, 'y': 0.1}
            id: include_num

        Label:
            text: 'Include special characters?'
            font_size: 35
            pos_hint: {'right': 0.85, 'top': 0.95}

        CheckBox:
            active: True
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.2, 'top': 0.95}
            id: include_special

        Button:
            text: 'Generate'
            font_size: (self.height - len(self.text) * 2) / 2
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.2
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.25, 'y': 0.1}
            on_release: root.generate()
```

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `CheckBox` is filling the entire `main` `Screen`. That happens because the default `size_hint` is `(1,1)`. Try setting a `size_hint` for all the widgets in your `kv`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was the solution I needed